# React Native Unable to resolve module

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-safe-area-context from C:\USER\App\NavigationApp\NavigationApp\node_modules\@react-navigation\stack\src\views\Stack\StackView.tsx: react-native-safe-area-context could not be found within the project.
```

I didn't wrote anything and just wanted to learn React Navigation. I installed @react-navigation/native and thought now I could start. But instead of JSX I get this error:
What to do?

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';


import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-navigation` package needs couple of other packages to work and `react-native-safe-area-context` is part of them, you only need to install it
`$ npm i --save react-native-safe-area-context`

Read more here (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)
Happy coding

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't saw it haha

Answer (score 1):

Did you installed dependencies of react navigation? `react-native-safe-area-context`  is one of the dependency. There are other dependencies that you should install for things to start work. To do so run this command if you are using expo managed workflow.

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

or if you are using bare work flow(react native CLI) run this

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Also you should read the offical installation [doc](http://react-native-safe-area-context)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have overlooked it haha

Comment: It seems your "doc" link is broken.